# Is valid to use this in a function that is called using shared pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a question about usage of shared pointers and multithreading programming in C++.
If I call a member function  using a shared pointer object of this class in thread A,
then is valid to use the this attribute inside the class and pass this in a callback function that will be triggered from thread B.
From my perspective if the thread A finishes its work then the shared pointer will be expired and this will be invalid.

Is valid to  use the shared_from_this and cast this to void*?

Hello here is the code. This code will generate a segmentation fault, right?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "ClassB.h"
class B;
class A
{
public:
        A()= default;

        void foo(void * ptr)
        {
            std::cout <<"enter in foo" <<std::endl;
            sleep(1);
            std::cout << "Thread wake up" << std::endl;
            B *pB = reinterpret_cast<B*>(ptr);
            pB->x = 5;
        }
};

void B::bar()
{
    std::cout << "enter in bar" << std::endl;
    void * ptr = reinterpret_cast<void *>(this);
    auto t2= std::thread(&A::foo,A(),ptr);
    t2.detach();
}

void threadTask()
{
    std::cout << "ThreadTask" << std::endl;
    std::shared_ptr<B> psharedB = std::make_shared<B>();
    auto t1 = std::thread(&B::bar,psharedB);
    t1.detach();
}

int main()
{
    auto t = std::thread(threadTask);
    t.join();
    sleep(20);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you 
George

Comment: 1. What programming lanuage? 2. Please provide a [mcve] to illustrate your question

Comment: "shared_from_this and cast this to void*?"  whatever reason you want to use void* for ... it's wrong, (probably from bad design) don't do it.

Comment: Yes I know. It is a bad design in existing code. But I cannot the this without use shared_from_this because this point to raw the object not to the shared pointer.right?

Comment: You need to write a simple test case - a class with a single `DoWork` method and a `main` that declares a `shared_ptr<>` of that class and uses that `shared_ptr` to call `DoWork`.  Inside the `DoWork` method show the code you are asking about - along with anything else needed to understand that code.  That's one way to provide the kind of [mcve] @UnholySheep suggested you add to your post.

Comment: @UnholySheep I provide a sample code.

Comment: There is no `shared_from_this` in your sample code and `reinterpret_cast<void*>(this);` is pretty much always wrong - why do you work with `void*` anyways? There's rarely any need to do this in C++ (and I certainly don't see it in your code). And there is never a guarantee that code will cause a segmentation fault, though your code looks like it will potentially invoke *undefined behavior*

Comment: Thanks for adding the example.  Using `unistd.h` and `sleep` means your code won't compile in some environments.  Using `chrono` and something like `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20)); ` instead will make your code more portable - and thus may increase the number of answers you'll get.  Also, at present the definition of `class B` is hidden in a header file we don't see.  Assuming standard constructors and destructors if you removed `ClassB.h` and expanded `class B;` to define the `bar()` method and the `x` member your example would be complete (i.e., it would compile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the object is allocated on the heap ( using `new`) it does not become invalid if the thread finishes. The `shared_pointer` stores a pointer to the instance on the heap and one pointer to the count variable. If the `shared_pointer` is copied, the count variable gets increased, if its destructor is called, it gets decreased. The destructor of your object is called by the shared pointer if the count gets 0, thus if no `shared_pointer`s point to the object any more. `shared_pointer` should be thread save even though this is very ressource intensive. It is important to know that if you pass a pointer to a `shared_pointer` the `shared_pointer` is now responsible for managing the instance, however it does not no about any other usage of the pointer. As a result, you should not call delete on the other pointers to the object.
Therefore it should not cause any conflicts if you allocate the object with `new`.

Edit:

This should not work as the `shared_pointer` will be destroyed as the thread is detached and the scope left and as `count=1` `B`should be destroyed.
Detaching a thread is always a bad idea.

Comment: Yes but in the callback function I passed the this. The this where is points to the shared_ptr  or in the raw pointer that has been used to create the shared pointer.

Comment: Is your object allocated on the stack or the heap

Comment: The object is allocated On the heap

Comment: _If the shared_pointer is copied, the count variable gets increased_ is true but I think you are assuming a copy that doesn't exist.  We're speculating about code we haven't seen but handing out `this` from inside a class doesn't affect any shared pointer that points to the class instance.

Comment: Then it should work anyways (if an instance of the shared pointer is kept alive)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> std::shared_ptr<B> psharedB = std::make_shared<B>();
> auto t1 = std::thread(&B::bar,psharedB);
> ```

I'm not a language lawyer but I think the code above will create an instance of class `B` pointed to by the shared pointer`psharedB` and then will create an instance of `std::thread` passing **by value** a function pointer to the method `B::bar` as the first parameter and passing **by value** a **copy** of `psharedB` as the second parameter.

Because a copy of `psharedB` is passed to the `thread ( … )` constructor, the shared pointer's reference count increases to two.  You can explore this by adding the following code to `threadTask` to examine the value of `psharedB.use_count()`after the new thread has been constructed …

```
auto t1 = std::thread(&B::bar, psharedB);
// show use count is two not one
std::cout << "psharedB use count: " << psharedB.use_count() << std::endl;
```

… the documentation warns that the value returned by use_count is "approximate" in a multithreaded environment but in this particular case it should be accurate.

When `threadtask` exits, `psharedB` goes out of scope.  The shared pointer's use count gets decremented by the shared pointer's destructor, but the `B` object instance is kept alive because the `psharedB` copy passed to the `t1` thread is still around so the use count is one not zero.

In `B::bar` the variable `this` is a plain ordinary raw `B *` pointer.  Underneath the covers it was extracted from the smart pointer passed to the `t1` thread but so far as the logic in `B::bar` is concerned we don't know that.  So, when that pointer is cast to `void *` it doesn't affect the shared pointer's use count at all.

One way to explore this would be to place a breakpoint on the `reinterpret_cast` in `B::bar` and run to that point.  The entry in the call stack immediately below the breakpoint will be the logic to invoke `B::bar` with the copy of `psharedB`.  The debugger should allow you to see the shared pointer and examine its use count which will either be one if `threadTask` has already exited or two if `threadTask` has not yet exited.

Step over the `reinterpret_cast` and observe that the shared pointer's use count doesn't change.

When `B::bar` returns, the `t1` thread launched by `threadTask` terminates.  Effectively the copy of `psharedB` passed to that thread goes out of scope and is destructed.  The shared pointer use count goes to zero and the `B` object instance originally created by `threadTask` is also destroyed.

At this point the `ptr` value passed to `foo` is a pointer to a deleted object instance.  Any attempt to dereference that `ptr` value inside `foo` will lead to undefined behaviour.  If you're lucky it crashes your program.  If you're unlucky the dereference appears to work and you get some difficult to track down failure later in your program's execution.  Or some weird behaviour that only happens sometimes and is very difficult to reproduce.

Worse yet, depending on *when* the `t1` thread is destroyed and thus *when* the `B` object instance is destroyed, the variable `ptr` within `foo` may be a valid `B*` pointer for some of `foo`'s execution and an invalid pointer for the rest of of `foo`'s execution.

> Is valid to use the shared_from_this and cast this to void*?

Your `A` and `B` classes do not derive from `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>` so in your example it is not valid to call `std::shared_from_this` in either class.

If you *did* create a `shared_ptr<B>` instance you would find that you can't cast it to `void *`.  Try adding `auto temp = reinterpret_cast<void *> (psharedB);` to `threadTask`.  You'll find you get a compiler error because the cast is an invalid conversion.

> Is it valid to use this in a function that is called using shared pointer

Yes it is valid - within certain limitations.  Your method `B::bar` invoked from `threadTask` is a function that is called using a shared pointer.  You can use `this` within `B::bar`.  But you don't get any special capability for `this` just because it was invoked using a shared pointer.  So far as `B::bar` is concerned it could have been invoked using a raw pointer like this …

```
B* p = new B();
p->bar();
```

Whether you are using a shared pointer or a raw pointer - it isn't valid to pass `this` or the `void *` version of `this` to another function like `A::foo` without ensuring that the instance the pointer points to will still be valid when `A::foo` comes to dereference that pointer.

If you are using `shared_ptr<T>` to control the lifespan of an object then ideally you want to pass `A::foo` a `shared_ptr<B>` parameter.  That way the object is kept alive by the `shared_ptr` passed to `A::foo` even if all the other shared pointers are destroyed.